# Flask with sqlalchemy how can i highlight my searched query results?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am making my app in which I'm querying my data base with like search and what I wanna do is to highlight the results which are showing in my result template. My search route looks like this:

```
@app.route("/post")

def post():

    term = request.args.get("search_text", None)
    if term == None:
        scanned = Images.query.filter_by().all()[0:15]
        return render_template('post.html', scanned=scanned)
    else:
        term = request.args.get("search_text")
        search = "%{}%".format(term)
        scanned = Images.query.filter(or_(Images.content.like(search),Images.title.like(search)))
        return render_template('post.html', scanned=scanned)
```

this my template file post.html

```
{% for scanned in scanned %}

  <div class="post-preview">


      <a href="/post2/{{scanned.Slug}}">
      <h2 class="post-title">{{ scanned.title }}
        
      </h2>
    </a>
    <p class="Images-meta">Posted by
      <a href="#">Admin</a>
      on {{scanned.Date}}</p>
  </div>

  {{scanned.content[0:120]}}...
  <hr>
    </li></a>
{% endfor %}
```

now everything is working fine but I just want to highlight my search query in results template.

Comment: How have you tried to highlight your results?

Answer (score 0):

You write the template 'post.html'. You need to modify that html file to change how things are displayed.

Comment: i have added the template code as well can you tell me how can i actually modify it?

Comment: I mean, however you want to...<b>? is this a school assignment?